# Google Python API tries to import the deprecated oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, oauth2client, google-python-api

I am trying to build the discovery docs for my endpoints application, but I am getting the following error:

```
pc@pc:~/backend$ endpointscfg.py get_discovery_doc [PROJECT_NAME]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/endpointscfg.py", line 10, in <module>
    import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping
  File "/home/pc/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 22, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
  File "/home/pc/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 30, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import creds
  File "/home/pc/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/creds.py", line 32, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib import multistore_file
ImportError: cannot import name multistore_file
```

The version of oauth2client is `4.1.0`. It seems the file `oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file` was deprecated and then removed from oauth2client (https://github.com/google/oauth2client/pull/589), so I assumed my google client libraries were out of date, but I have run `gcloud components update app-engine-python` and I still get the same error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the solution is that you have to use an older version of oauth2client. If you ensure you have the latest (`1.1.2`) version of google-endpoints-api-management, then you will want to install google-apitools version `0.5.11` and oauth2client version `3.0.0`.

Comment: It's still a problem as of today. I have google_endpoints `4.6.1` + google_endpoints_api_management `1.10.0` + google_apitools `0.5.24` + oauth2client `3.0.0`. I checked the source code and it seems `apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py` in particular is the one that import `multistore_file` and caused the problem. Maybe it can be updated to refer to new/recommended module?

Comment: Also for context, this problem causes very slow responses (> 13 seconds) for some of my requests.

Comment: There is no available replacement for these modules.

Comment: How do we fix this error? Some of my appengine project responses are taking a very long time

Comment: We can't fix it. The newest versions don't work on App Engine and never will.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I just migrated a project from V1 of endpoints and am receiving this error after following: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/migrating

Comment: Nope, there's no possible fix for this issue due to App Engine not allowing the new versions. All you can do is stick with the older versions that are allowed.